# Find where line intersects sine function

Tags: trigonometry

Here we have sin((x+1)*(pi/2)):

[image: 1]

Now let's say we have a point at (x=2, y=1)...

[image: 2]

And we draw a line to the origin (x=0, y=0)...

[image: 2]

If we create a point where the line intersects the sine function, we get a new point.
Is there a way to find out the (x,y) of this new point?

[image]

Comment: The line has equation $x = 2y$, so this reduces to find $y$ such that $y = \sin((2y+1)\frac{\pi}{2})$. It can be solved numerically with Newton's method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $x$ coordinate of the point of intersection is the unique positive number such that $\sin(\pi(x+1)/2) = x/2$.  This equation cannot be solved in closed form but Newton's method shows the solution is approximately $0.7539340187865513$.

To apply Newton's method, define $f(x)=\sin(\pi(x+1)/2) - x/2$.  Then 
$$N(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (x+1)\right)-\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} \pi  \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \pi  (x+1)\right)-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Iterating $N$ from the starting point $x_0 = 1.0$, we generate the sequence

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 1.0000000000000000 \\
 0.7585469929947761 \\
 0.7539390100743306 \\
 0.753934018792478 \\
 0.7539340187865515 \\
 0.7539340187865514 \\
 0.7539340187865513 \\
 0.7539340187865514 \\
 0.7539340187865513 \\
\end{array}
$$

Thus, it appears the solution is between $0.7539340187865513$ and $0.7539340187865513$.

Comment: You meant between 0.7539340187865513 and 0.7539340187865514, right?

Answer (score 1):

The line through $\;(2,1)\;$ and through the origin is $\;y=\frac12x\;$ , so you need to solve

$$\sin\left(\frac\pi2(x+1)\right)=\frac12x$$

This yields a transcendental equation which would hardly have a simple, nice-looking zero, but:

$$h(x)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2(x+1)\right)-\frac12x\implies\begin{cases}h(0)=1\\{}\\h(1)=-\frac12\end{cases}$$

Now apply the Mean Value Theorem (=Lagrange's Theorem) to $\;h\;$ and deduce the existence of a point like the one you're interested in. If you want the *actual* value of the point's coordinates you may need to repeat the above several times, or use some other approximation methods (say, Newton's)

Comment: +1 Exactly my approach, which will not be posted (has now been "discarded", as you beat me to it!) ;-)